# backbone.js infinite pagination display issue

Tags: jquery, html, backbone.js, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js-collections

I'm using backbone [infinite pagination](https://github.com/addyosmani/backbone.paginator). Take a look at this image. Before I click "more" everything is ok. Once I click "more" then new results are added fine, but the "more button" is not pushed down.

[image]

this is my template (I use twitter bootstrap), though I've also tried to put the "more" button directly after the "users-list" div which also did not work.

```
<div class="row"> 
    <div class="span2">
        <div id="users-list" style="height:50px"></div>        
    </div>
</div>


<div class="row">  
    <div class="span2">
        <ul class="pager">  
          <li>
            <a href="#" id="more">More</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is how I add new results in the view code:

```
    //in initialize()
    this.list = $("#users-list", this.el)

    ...

    //in render()
    _.each(this.model.models, function (user) {            
        this.list.append(new User({model:user}).render().el);
    }, this);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue is because you have a height of 50px set to your user-list. I'm not sure why you have that in the first place, there might be a reason, but when you do add more items to it dynamically, the height either needs to grow dynamically or you can simply remove it.

```
 <div id="users-list" style="height:50px"></div>
```